# onclick javascript function needs to "turn on and off" div property with subsequent clicks

Tags: java, javascript, html, css

I have an HTML button with an `onclick` JavaScript function to make a div visible with the display property. It works great.

But I want subsequent clicks to toggle the display settings from displayed back to not displayed. I feel like I could just assign values within the function for zero and one with an if else statement.

Here is my code, it doesn't work.

```
<Button id="IDButton" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
    <img id="thisIMG" src="thisIMG.png">
</Button>

<script>   
    function myFunction() { 
        var a;
    if (a < 1) {
        document.getElementById("hiddenMenuDiv").style.display = "block";
        a=1;
    }
    else (a >= 1) {         
        document.getElementById("hiddenMenuDiv").style.display = "none";
        a=0;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this for why your code doesn't work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

And here's a suggestion for an improvement:

```
function myFunction() { 
    var element = document.getElementById("hiddenMenuDiv");
    if (element.style.display === "block") {
        element.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        element.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: As your answer got accepted, please mention the mistake on the line of the "else" so others see it.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring

```
var a;
```

every time you click on the button.

The variable **a** is in the scope of the function, so its value is not persisted between calls.

You don't really need that variable though.

Try this:

```
<script>   
    function myFunction() { 
      var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("hiddenMenuDiv")
      if (hiddenDiv.style.display != "none") {
        hiddenDiv.style.display = "none";
      }
      else {          
        hiddenDiv.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: Some more ways to toggle visibility of a control:
 http://www.dustindiaz.com/seven-togglers/

Also, an else cannot have a condition associated:

```
else (a >= 1) {
```

this is not valid javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It's because value of a is not remembered between function runs (since it's a local variable).

I would suggest somehting like this

```
if (document.getElementById("hiddenMenuDiv").style.display === "block")
     document.getElementById("hiddenMenuDiv").style.display = "none";
else
     document.getElementById("hiddenMenuDiv").style.display = "block";
```

Or make a a global variable

Answer (score 1):

Frequently this would be solved using something like jQuery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method.

In your case, the main problem is that you're defining a new "a" variable every time, instead of storing it in the global scope somewhere. So when the end of the function is reached, "a" no longer exists. The next time it's called, it's back to being undefined (which, since you don't initialize it, gets coerced to 0 for comparison purposes).

You don't strictly need this variable at all though, because you already have a good way to know if the element is hidden or not - the style.display value.

So, you could rewrite your script as:

```
function toggleMenu() {
    var menuDiv = document.getElementById("hiddenMenuDiv");
    if (menuDiv.style.display == "block") {
        menuDiv.style.display = ""; // Assuming it defaults to 'none' in CSS. Or you could specify it here.
    }
    else {
        menuDiv.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Often, though, an even better practice would be to avoid touching the element's inline style settings, and just have a "hidden" CSS class, which the element starts with and you can remove and re-add in response to clicking the button.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on closures. Try this:

```
myFunction = (function(){
    var isVisible = false; // Change to true if div is visible to start
    return function(){
        elem = document.getElementById("hiddenMenuDiv");
        elem.style.display = (isVisible) ? "none" : "block";
        isVisible = !isVisible;
    };
})();
```

Edit: I originally had 'function' before myFunction. Oops. Correct now.

Comment: Sorry, but this makes no sense, and is syntactically incorrect in multiple ways.

Comment: Oops. Supposed to to be myFunction =  ... instead of function myFunction =... Fixing now.

Comment: Yeah the "function myFunction = function" thing was one problem I remember this having. But it's also the most bizarre/convoluted way I could fathom to solve this problem. It's a lot more code and runtime overhead (not to mention just plain confusing use of language concepts) for something with way simpler and more efficient solutions. And it still has the problem of having an unnecessary state variable awkwardly coupled to the actual UI state.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the function, you're missing a "}" at the end. Also, better to put the function definition before the button to avoid a "myFunction not defined" error.

Comment: Presumably the function actually lives in a JS file, not embedded in a script tag here. And while technically it makes more sense to have it first, that's not a realistic problem to hit in this case.